# How to read the all node tables in corda

Tags: corda

I want to read the all tables of node.I am able to read the data of vault states but not the other tables. Could you please tell me how to access the data of each and every table data of node.

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect directly to the node's database using JDBC.

If your node is using an H2 database, try following the instructions here: https://docs.corda.net/node-database-access-h2.html#connecting-using-the-h2-console.

Comment: using h2 i am able to do, but i want do it using API